# How can i override Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods

Now i use to override extensions like :

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    public new MyHtmlHelper<T> Html { get; set; }
    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        Ajax = new AjaxHelper<T>(ViewContext, this);
        Url = new UrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext);
        Html = new MyHtmlHelper<T>(ViewContext, this);
    }
}

public class MyHtmlHelper<T> : HtmlHelper<T>
{
    public MyHtmlHelper(ViewContext viewContext, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) :
        base(viewContext, viewDataContainer)
    {
    }

    public MvcHtmlString ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName)
    {
        return ActionLink(linkText, actionName, null, new RouteValueDictionary(), new RouteValueDictionary());
    } 
}
```

How to add `Url.Action` helper here with all overloaded version?

**UPD:** I should override all standard method because many peoples work on this and i they should use standard helpers but with my functionality

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to override neither the `Url.Action` helper nor the `HtmlHelper` actions. You can create [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb383977.aspx) instead. Here's an example:

```
public static class MyHelpers
{
    public static string MyAction(this UrlHelper url, string actionName)
    {
        // return whatever you want (here's an example)...
        return url.Action(actionName, new RouteValueDictionary());
    }
}
```

Then, you can use the method in your views like this:

```
@Url.MyAction("MyActionName")
```

**UPDATE:**

I wouldn't recommend overriding the `Url.Action` method. Creating extension methods is much easier and cleaner. But, here's how you can do it:

```
public class MyUrlHelper : UrlHelper 
{
    public override string Action(string actionName)
    {
        return base.Action(actionName, new RouteValueDictionary());  
    }
}
```

Comment: I should override all standard method because many peoples work on this and i they should use standard helpers but with my functionality

Comment: That's not a good idea. The fact that many people are going to use the methods, is not a good reason. But, anyway, check my updated answer.

Comment: @PeteFox, why do you want to create a new class just to override one method? Extension classes are used for this purpose. Renaming the existing `Url.Action` calls in the views shouldn't be very difficult. It's just some find/replace.